# AddClass to Bootstrap Carousel item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a standard bootstrap carousel https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/.
Each time a slide is changed, the `".active"` class is added to the `".carousel-item"`.
I need to add another class to the child element.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="someClass active"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="someClass"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="someClass"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> carousel-item.active --> someClass.active

And I did it with onClick function:

```
$('.carousel-control-next').on('click', function () {
    $('.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active').find('.someClass').addClass('active');
});
```

However, I do not need this to work when auto-playing slides through an interval.

I tried to use the *"MutationObserver"* to add a class immediately after the change of the DOM, but the specifics of the Bootstrap Carousel work is such that 3 changes of the classes are used at once and it does not work very well.

Comment: Maybe I'm having trouble understanding, but you **do** need this to work when auto-playing slides, or **don't** need it to?

Comment: Why would you possibly need to add another class if you are looking for a child of the active class then just target it by .carousel-item.active .yourElement.

Comment: Checkout the this [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#events) ..

Answer (score -1):

Well, I did a great nonsense...
Bootstrap’s carousel already has [two events for this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#events).
*Thanks Arup Rakshit*